# Options "Apply" button

Tags: c#

I tried to add an Apply button to my Options form but it wouldn't work.

Here's what I've tried:

in `frm_Main`

```
frm_Options Options = new frm_Options();
Options.btn_Apply.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Apply_Click);
```

Later...

```
Options.Show();
```

...

```
void btn_Apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadPreferences();
}
```

Basically the only way I could think of doing it was to add an even handler from `frm_Main` to the button in `frm_Options`. My guess is you can't do this, is there another way or is it possible the way I tried to do it?

Edit1:
I want to do this in frm_Main because I want the button, when pressed, to call a function in `frm_Main`
And by "doesn't work" I mean the event doesn't fire when the "Apply" button is clicked

Comment: Why do you do this in `frm_Main`?

Comment: What does "It wouldn't work" mean exactly? The event handler doesn't fire? Or something else?

Comment: Hi kschiek, you seem to be missing some important details.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question - but I think you want an event in the Options form which the main form subscribes to - so when you click the button in the options form the main form is notified.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do @NDJ. My bad for not explaining well enough, I though that would have been apparent from context. My mistake.

Comment: I've given an answer which should help you on your way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your event within the options form

```
public event EventHandler RefreshOptions;
```

and in the button click event raise the event (if it has a subscriber) - e.g.

```
 var refreshOptions = RefreshOptions;
        if (refreshOptions != null)
            refreshOptions(this, new EventArgs());
```

Then subscribe to the event in your main form -

```
Options options = new Options();
options.RefreshOptions += MainRefresh;
```

and create the MainRefresh event (or whatever you call it)

```
 void MainRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // TODO
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot with other things too.